# Convert clustered obj to array

Tags: javascript

I want to use the library [markdown-table](https://github.com/wooorm/markdown-table) to generate out of my object a table. The pre-requirement is to create an array with a certain structure.

Find below my minimum viable example:

```js
const obj = {
  "2": {
    "title": "Product 1",
    "category": [{
      "cat_name": "Graphic Card"
    }],
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "513.40"
  },
  "3": {
    "title": "Product 2",
    "category": [{
      "cat_name": "Graphic Card"
    }],
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "599.00",
  },
  "4": {
    "title": "Memory Ram 1",
    "category": [{
      "cat_name": "Memory"
    }],
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "25.99",
  },
  "5": {
    "title": "Product 3",
    "category": [{
      "cat_name": "Graphic Card"
    }],
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "688.88",
  },
  "6": {
    "title": "Adapter 1",
    "category": [{
      "cat_name": "PCI-E"
    }],
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "48.99",
  }
}


var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), obj[key]];
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wooorm/markdown-table/master/index.js"></script>
```

I am getting the following result for my table:

```
| 2   | [object Object] |
| --- | --------------- |
| 3   | [object Object] |
| 4   | [object Object] |
| 5   | [object Object] |
| 6   | [object Object] |
```

However, the result array I am trying to get should look like the following:

```
[
  ['Category', 'Model', 'Price'],
  ['Graphic Card', 'Prod 1', '$513.40'],
  ['Graphic Card', 'Product 2', '$599.00'],
  ['Graphic Card', 'Product 3', '$688.88'],
  ['Memory', 'Memory Ram 1', '$25.99'],
  ['PCI-E', 'Adapter 1', '$48.99']
]
```

Any suggestions why my array is not parsed correctly and `[object Object]` is shown?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3):

`[object Object]` what you get when you call .toString() on an object.

It looks like you need to explicitly pass markdown-table the values you want displayed, as all it's doing is calling .toString() on what you pass in.  I don't see where it will derive the headers and values for you.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
let result = Object.keys(obj)
    .reduce((result, key) => {
        result.push([obj[key].category[0].cat_name, obj[key].title, obj[key].currency + obj[key].price]);
        return result;
    },
    [['Category', 'Model', 'Price']]
);
```

What's going on here is I'm passing in the headers as the initial value of the accumulator in .reduce(), and each iterations is pushing a row of values onto the accumulated array.

If you want to sort the results:

```
let result = Object.keys(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => {
        if (obj[a].category[0].cat_name < obj[b].category[0].cat_name)
            return -1;
        if (obj[a].category[0].cat_name > obj[b].category[0].cat_name)
            return 1;
        if (obj[a].model < obj[b].model)
            return -1;
        if (obj[a].model > obj[b].model)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    })
    .reduce(...
```

Here's a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/t8Lvw2bj/2/

Comment: Thx for your reply! Any suggestions how to sort the columns by Category alphabetically?

Comment: Thx! I would love to have all "rows" sorted by Category and then by model in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` to get the values from your object and then using `array#map` with `object and array destructuring` you can generate the desired array. Then using `local#compare` and `array#sort`, sort the array alphabetically. Then you using `array#unshift` you can add the `['Category', 'Model', 'Price']` at the beginning of array.

```js
const obj = { "2": {"title": "Product 1", "category": [{ "cat_name": "Graphic Card" }], "currency": "$", "price": "513.40" }, "3": { "title": "Product 2", "category": [{ "cat_name": "Graphic Card" }], "currency": "$", "price": "599.00", }, "4": { "title": "Memory Ram 1","category": [{ "cat_name": "Memory" }], "currency": "$", "price": "25.99", }, "5": { "title": "Product 3", "category": [{ "cat_name": "Graphic Card" }], "currency": "$", "price": "688.88", }, "6": { "title": "Adapter 1", "category": [{ "cat_name": "PCI-E"}], "currency": "$", "price": "48.99", } };
let result = Object
    .values(obj)
    .map(({title, category : [{cat_name}], currency, price}) => [cat_name, title, `${currency}${price}`])
    .sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) || a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));
result.unshift(['Category', 'Model', 'Price']);
console.log(result);
```